# Mod Rewrite rule for pagiantion

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, pagination, url-rewrite-module

My home page url is

`http://example.com/subsite`

My pagination hover link shows

`http://example.com/subsite/?page=2`
but it redirects back to  `http://example.com/subsite`

whereas it should show and also go to `http://example.com/subsite/page/2` which works (if i try manually). Here is my htaccess file looks like,

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subsite/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /subsite/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

How to fix the pagination rewrite rule?

Comment: This reads like there is a miss understanding on your side of what URL rewriting actually does: I understand "My pagination hover link" as the reference you yourself publish with tht html code you generate and hand out. That is something that cannot be changed by URL rewriting, you need to fix that in your application logic. URL rewriting only acts on _incoming_ http requests to your http server. So it can map a pretty URL back to the internal technical notation.

Comment: @arkascha its a wordpress theme doing it. It doesnt give option to configure urls

Comment: Wordpress is very well able to generate pretty URLs...

Comment: so, how to solve this?